# How to make screens appear only after installation in react native expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-screens

I have a few welcome screens that should only appear once, when the app is first launched after installation, but I have no idea how.

My app is in `react-native 0.64.3` and `expo 43.0.2`

Thank you in advance

Comment: set a loading screen, and set a timeout so when the timeout is over you move to your mane screen

Comment: @chikabala I don't think that's what I need. I need to have 3 screens that navigate from one to another that have some info on them. And it should appear only after first launching an app, not every time you launch it. Thanks for the answer tho :)

Comment: You need to store a value based on if the user has completed your tasks, using e.g. AsyncStorage or react-native-mmkv-(storage).

Comment: @NemanjaMitric i got you now, please check my answer and let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AsyncStorage` will do the job for you, you can use it along with `componentDidMount`

```
async componentDidMount() {
  const firstTime = await AsyncStorage.getItem("isFirstTime")
  if(firstTime != null) {
    // navigate to HomePage directly
  } else {
    // navigate to other screens where you have some infos to show
    await AsyncStorage.setItem("isFirstTime", 'true')
  }
}
```